# Is Harry a shapeshifter or is his ability an illusion?

Tags: resident-alien

Harry is an alien who can appear to be a human.  But the rules seem poorly defined.  Early on in the series, it's made clear that Max has a rare genetic condition that allows him to see through Harry's trick, which makes it seem like an illusion.  But later, several times, Harry seems surprised or confused about his human form.  He's surprised when he gets an erection, mistaking it for rigor mortis, and he is confused about needing sleep, both of which make it seem he physically is a human.  But if he actually is physically human, how can Max see him as an alien?  Am I just taking this too seriously?

Comment: [Early installment weirdness](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/EarlyInstallmentWeirdness), perhaps?

Answer (score 4):

Harry refers to this ability as his "genetic cloak".

My interpretation is that he really has physically transformed himself into a human, given the evidence you provide and other examples in the series like his development of human emotions.

But certain humans/beings, like Max and later Peter Bach, are somehow born with a genetic "sixth sense" that tells them Harry is definitely not human. This consciously manifests as visually seeing Harry as clearly alien, even though no one else can. This ability also seems to extend to seeing Harry in his 'correct' form, as he is able to describe his alien features in detail.